# Controlling recyclerView item object's from out side the item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an `EditText etPosition` , `Button btnSelectThePosition` and a `RecyclerView` each item has a layout of 2 `TextViews` and 1 `EditText`.
Is it possible to edit one of the objects *Not The Data* from outside the `recyclerView`?
For Example, if I passed the value "9" in the `etPosition` and clicked the `btnSelectThePosition`, I want the `EditText` in the item position 9 in the `recyclerView` to call `selectAll`.
Open for any suggestions

Comment: @Zoe Ok Sorry , Thanks for saying.